# Create a multi-step form based on user input

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-library

I need to create multiple "forms" (e.g. login, signup) and you should be able to fill in one information at a time.

After the user entered his first name he should swipe (like in `ViewPager`) and the next input should appear dependent on the previous (if he wants the newsletter, the next step should be entering the mail).

Some of the inputs are very complex like ordering items in a list and I thought it would be a good idea to use `Fragments` and the `ViewPager` but it is not.

The `ViewPager` doesn't handle the dependency on the previous input very well and it is not really possible to add custom animations.

I didn't find a library that fits my needs... Do you have an idea what I can do?

Comment: If you want swipe use the viewpager, you will need to implement the rest of your logic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Will this library fit  your needs:

https://github.com/romannurik/Android-WizardPager